# iterating strings in python with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Why this is iteration is not working  ? while the same works if words is replaced by range(len(words)) in the for loop

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += words[i]
    return result

print join_strings(n)
```

Comment: In you add `print(i)` in the loop, you will see that `i` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @tarashypka thanks for the clarification. Can u please suggest an alternate to get the answer without using range() function

Answer (score 2):

Your code.

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

def join_strings(words):
    # words = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        # i = 'Michael' for the first iteration.
        # if you do range(len(words)) then i=0 and words[0] is valid then
        result += words[i] #<--Error! i='Michael' and you can't do words['Michael']
    return result

print join_strings(n)
```

Pythonic way of joining strings in the list:

```
print ''.join(n) #Outputs --> MichaelLieberman
```

Comment: it's not only a pythonic problem: using string concatenation is under-performant, and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a string value not index. You can use `enumerate` function:

```
for index, i in enumerate(words): 
    result += words[index]
```

or you can just use the word itself:

```
for i in words:
    result += i
```

---

Performance:

```
In [14]: timeit.timeit('string_cat', '''def string_cat():
    ...:     rg = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
    ...: 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    ...:     st = ''
    ...:     for x in rg: st += x
    ...: ''', number=1000000)
Out[14]: 0.02700495719909668

In [15]: timeit.timeit('string_cat', '''def string_cat():
    ...:     rg = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
    ...: 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    ...:     st = ''.join(rg)
    ...: ''', number=1000000)
Out[15]: 0.026237964630126953
```

Comment: first solution is unpythonic like hell, and both are highly inefficient. don't use that code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  surprisingly, after testing, string concatenation is not necessarily worse than join; that said, I definitely prefer join myself.

Comment: you have to perform _real_ test, with big strings. reallocation/memory copy is the actual problem. I've been there myself. and in-place doesn't help a bit because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

if you r using for loop like :

```
for i in words:
```

then do like this :

```
result += i
```

because here we are taking values from list directly without mentioning any range or it's size.

if u r using for loop like :

```
for i in range(len(words)):
```

then do like this :

```
result += words[i]
```

and the output will be same from both the cases :

```
MichaelLieberman
```

for better clarification about for loop refer this : 
https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops